# Unable to add .hidden class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a little stuck here. Unable to figure out the reason. Any help will be appericiated.

**Original Element**

***HTML***

```
<div class="row slide active"></div>
```

**Applied JavaScript**

***JavaScript***

```
//storing element into variable    
var active_slide = jQuery('.slide.active.row'); 

//removing a class    
active_slide.removeClass('active');

//adding a new class
active_slide.addClass('hidden');
```

***Result***

```
<div class="row slide"></div>
```

***Expected Result***

```
<div class="row slide hidden"></div>
```

Comment: there is no reason code shown won't work as it is...please provide demo that replicates problem

Comment: i can't see any wrong - jeck this http://jsfiddle.net/25g2S/

Comment: Double-check that you're selecting the right element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1

Why don't you remove the whole of the class, and add the class that you want. This way,

```
$('button').click(function () { // or any other element; even onload
    $('div').attr('class', ''); // remove the class; empty the attribute
    $('div').attr('class', 'row slide hidden'); // add class
})
```

You can handle each and every attribute of the element using `attr()` and then adding or updating or removing the content of it. Its a bit handy for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/ea8Fm/ (test it here)

#### Option 2:

Our friend charlietfl didn't like this solution, so here is the Remove and AddClass solution

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').removeClass(); // remove class
    $('div').addClass('row slide hidden'); // add class
})
```

You need to add the whole class, so that this whole class is applied and you might need to remove the previous class; updating the class at a whole.

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/HnwJd/ (test this one here)

#### Your code:

And as far as your code is concerned, the result is exactly the same as you want it to be!

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/25g2S/2/

I used same code, and the result was the one you desired for.

Comment: this is nothing but a hack for something that should already work. There is nothing wrong with `addClass` or `removeClass` methods

Comment: OP's code will work also. Just because OP says it's not working, it's likely due to something not shown. Your solution doesn't provide any reason to avoid using `addClas` or `removeClass` which are common place methods

Comment: see...you gave 2 workarounds for something that already works....that was my main point all along

Comment: What else can I provide now? His code works, but he is saying it doesn't! I can't test his code any further you know that too. I just provided him a workaround to test the working of the code! Nothing else..

Comment: you can't..and sometimes it's best not to answer....what you ended up pointing out was already pointed out long before you answered

Answer (score 0):

```
var active_slide = jQuery('.slide active row'); 
                   active_slide.removeClass();
                   active_slide.addClass('row slide hidden');
```

Comment: if you are dealing with dynamic data use Jquery live or on event handler and refer to element by $(this)

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this problem by javascript,I think there is some bug with jquery.

```
var active_slide = jQuery('.slide.active.row'); 

//removing a class    
active_slide.removeClass('active');

//adding a new class
active_slide[0].className+=' hidden';
```